# How do I add an item to a TListBox and associate it with a data object?

Tags: delphi, listview, listbox, listboxitems

See the code:

```
function ShowItem(MyData: TMyData): TListItem;
var
  vListItem: TListItem;
begin
  vListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  vListItem.Data := MyData;

  vListItem.ImageIndex := 1;
  vListItem.Caption := MyData.Caption;

  Result := vListItem;
end;
```

What do I need to do to get this to work for TListBox? ListView.Items property seems to be that of TListItem, where as ListBox.Items is not, which means the function will not be able to return the correct parameter for TListBox.

How may I convert this for TListBox?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do:

```
function ShowItem(MyData: TMyData): Integer;
begin
  Result := ListBox1.Items.AddObject(MyData.Caption, MyData);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent since the ImageIndex property for list views has no analogue for list boxes (unless you implement it yourself and custom draw).